# Enabling Log Verbosity

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting the following warning in VB.NET VS 2015:

Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

How can I change the log verbosity? I can't find it under Project->Settings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link - looks like what I need...
[Log Verbosity](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/11/26/back-to-basic-displaying-detailed-output-of-msbuild-in-visual-studio-output-window/)

In summary, in VS2015 navigate to Tools –> Options –> Projects and Solutions –> Build and Run 
then look for "MSBuild project build log file verbosity" and make the desired change.